# How to factorise this?

Tags: factoring

Could any one help me factorising this term. I know the answer but I don't know how to get there. Thank you for your time.

$$-x+x\cos(x)+\cos(x)\sin(x)-\sin(x)=(\cos(x)-1)(x+\sin(x))$$

How do I get there? Is there a simple way to factorise terms like this?

Comment: Factor an $x$ (or $-x$, if you prefer) out of the first two terms and a $\sin(x)$ out of the second two terms.  *Et voila*.

Comment: Expand the product on the right !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is "factoring by grouping."  Factor $x$ out of the first two terms and factor $\sin x$ out of the last two terms.  The two blobs left both have a factor of $(\cos x -1)$, so factor that out.

Answer (score 1):

First factor the terms with $x$
$$-x+x\cos(x)+\cos(x)\sin(x)-\sin(x)=x[\cos(x)-1]+\cos(x)\sin(x)-\sin(x)$$
Then factor terms with sine
$$x[\cos(x)-1]+\cos(x)\sin(x)-\sin(x)=x[\cos(x)-1]+\sin(x)[\cos(x)-1]$$
Now factor $\cos(x)-1$ to obtain your result
$$x[\cos(x)-1]+\sin(x)[\cos(x)-1]=(\cos(x)-1)(x+\sin(x))$$

Answer (score 1):

Just begin with obvious partial factorisations, in the hope there will be a common factor:
\begin{align}
-x+x\cos x+\cos x\sin x-\sin x&=-x+\cos x(x+\sin x)-\sin x\\
&=\cos x(x+\sin x)-(x+\sin x)\\
&=(\cos x-1)(x+\sin x).
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

There is not a general rule, you to practice with this kind of manipulations.

A good hint is try to group toghether step by step similar terms as follow:

$$-x+x\cos(x)+\cos(x)\sin x-\sin x$$

$$-x+\cos x(x+\sin x)-\sin x$$

$$\cos x(x+\sin x)-(x+\sin x)$$

$$(\cos x-1) (x+\sin x)$$

Answer (score 0):

Taking it from where everyone else got:

Look at the left part($\cos(x)-1$). Set $2a=x$ to get $$\cos(2a)-1$$ now multiply by $-1$ twice to get $-(1-\cos(2a))$, this should ring a bell to you, remember the double angle formulas $$\cos(2\theta)=1-2\sin^2(\theta)$$hence we get $\cos(2a)-1=-(1-\cos(2a))=-(1-(1-2\sin^2(a)))=-2\sin^2(a)$ plug $x=2a$ to get $-2\sin^2(\frac x2)$ hence you have the reduced form of $$\boxed{-2\sin^2\left(\frac x2\right)(x+\sin(x))}$$